# How do I implement LIBSVM for multiclass classification using java?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, java

I am currently working on an image classification project ,where i need to use bag of features model with libsvm(HIK kernel) for classification.I have extracted sift feature and created a visual vocabulary,my fetaures are double values.But LIBSVM works with only integer values.Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libsvm doesn't work with only integer values -- in fact, you're supposed to scale your features to lie within [-1,1] or [0,1] before applying SVM's typically. Read their [guide](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf). They also have some tricks for dealing with categorical features as well.

If you want to get finitely many values which the feature can take, use [quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization).